# PHPExcel cell height only works on empty cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've read a couple of examples on google but i cannot find anything like my issue.

To set the cell height i use:
`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);`

This will set cell height to "auto".
I guess the text/data will deside it's height?!

I have tried several values like: 4, 10 etc..

Strange is that only the cell without any text will change height.

I'm thinking: Does the text/font has a margin-top value?
I cannot see any type of height limit, so that should not be the prob.

**CODE**

```
//Set font Size
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:I".$highestRow)->getFont()->setSize(4);

//Set Row size
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(6);
```

**Example**

[image]

I'd like the cell height to be as height as the text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem i had to set each row height in my loop where i set cell values.

```
//Loop out data into cells (create excel)
while($value = $stmt->fetch()){

    //Set start Column
    $column = "A";

    //Set row height
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row)->setRowHeight(6);

//Set cell values
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The row height limit is actually 409.50 (546 pixels), which is the MS Excel limit for the OfficeOpenXML (xlsx)format. It's simply that PHPExcel doesn't enforce it.

And if you look at some of the Examples (such as `01Simple.php`) you'll see the height being set automatically for rows 8 and 10. In your case, it looks as though you have a newline character before the text that you're setting in your cells, so they're spanning 2 lines, and the autoheight is setting itself accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so there is a height limit. But it should not interfear with my font size 4. If i open the exported sheet and mark a cell with text i cannot move the marker up or down.. so it seems only to be one line of text in each cell. Or do i get you wrong?